# Locate the url from which the update is downloaded, and on which url checks the existence of the update

Tags: vlc-media-player, updates, wireshark, url

Install the VLC player and locate the url from which the update is downloaded, and on which url checks the existence of the update.

Could someone explain how to do this? What tools to use? Is Wireshark the tool to use?

I have a VLC version 2. After I have done "check for updates", Wireshark gives the following (image):

[image]

This url should be the one that checks the existence of the update. Is this correct?

After running "check for updates", VLC says: "An error occurred while checking for updates". This stops me from finding the url from which the update is downloaded.

How to find that url? I have also tried with version 3 (the newest one), but after running "check for updates" it says: "No updates available".

Answer (score 0):

> Is Wireshark the correct tool to use?

Yes.

> This URL should be the one that checks the existence of the update. Is this correct?

Yes.

> How to find the URL from which the update is downloaded?

It seems like the update URL is packaged in the data returned by http://update.videolan.org/vlc/status-win-x86 (taken from your Wireshark data). When visiting that URL via http (e.g. in a browser), the data stream returned is:

```
2.2.6
http://get.videolan.org/vlc/2.2.6/win32/vlc-2.2.6-win32.exe
VideoLAN and the VLC development team present VLC 2.2.6 "Umbrella".
VLC 2.2.6 is a security update fixing issues with subtitles and other formats, and improving DLL-loading security. VLC media player 2.2.0 was a major upgrade of VLC, introduced accelerated auto-rotation of videos, 0-copy hardware acceleration, support for UHD codecs, playback resume, integrated extensions and more than 1000 bugs and improvements.
```

A similar data stream with a different URL is returned by http://update.videolan.org/vlc/status-win-x64:

```
2.2.6
http://get.videolan.org/vlc/2.2.6/win64/vlc-2.2.6-win64.exe
VideoLAN and the VLC development team present VLC 2.2.6 "Umbrella".
VLC 2.2.6 is a security update fixing issues with subtitles and other formats, and improving DLL-loading security. VLC media player 2.2.0 was a major upgrade of VLC, introduced accelerated auto-rotation of videos, 0-copy hardware acceleration, support for UHD codecs, playback resume, integrated extensions and more than 1000 bugs and improvements.
```

Currently, VLC 3.0.1 seems to check the same URLs.

Interestingly, even when spoofing the User-Agent string VLC 3.0.1 sends (`VLC/3.0.1 LibVLC/3.0.1`), the same data for VLC 2.2.6 is returned. At a guess, this could mean there is a delay in automated version updates (despite what is publicly available) or there is some other additional (unknown) criteria used to determine proper updates.